# How to get last event from the `fromEvent` method

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-directive, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am trying to catch the last event from the `keyup` using `rxjs` but getting bunch of console all the way.

here is my angular directive:

```
import { Directive, AfterContentChecked, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, merge, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged, debounceTime, last, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFocuser]'
})
export class FocuserDirective implements AfterContentChecked {
  focusableArray = [];
  parent = null;
  count = 0;
  currentFocus: HTMLElement;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.parent = this.el.nativeElement;
    this.focusableArray = Array.from(this.parent.querySelectorAll(`[data-focus=true]`));
    this.currentFocus = this.focusableArray[0] as HTMLElement;
    if (this.currentFocus) {
      this.currentFocus.focus();
      this.count++;
    }

    this.eventHandler();
  }

  eventHandler() {
    const events = fromEvent(this.parent, 'keyup')
      .pipe(debounceTime(100))
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
    events.pipe().subscribe(console.log); //each time consoles 7,8
  }
  //
}
```

what is the correct way to handle this?

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jaauhp?file=src/app/directives/autoFocusable.directive.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can try last operator if you want only the last event:

```
eventHandler() {
    const events = fromEvent(this.parent, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
       debounceTime(100),
       distinctUntilChanged(),
       last());

    events.pipe().subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

If you want to take 2 last events you can try this:

```
eventHandler() {
    const events = fromEvent(this.parent, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
       debounceTime(100),
       distinctUntilChanged(),
       takeLast(2));

    events.pipe().subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

Comment: i think last and takeLast only work when the observable completes, which should never happen with the fromEvent Observable

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jaauhp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2FautoFocusable.directive.ts - no luck